# No baking right

Tags: solo-baking

I have been baking for over 30 days, but my baker logs always show the following:

```
client.nonce_revelation: Nothing to reveal for block BLjjy3pgs8pN
Apr 15 05:23:46 xxxx /var/log/tezos/tezos_baking.log[8263]: Apr 15 05:23:46 - client.baking: No slot found at level 395863 (max_priority = 64)
```

Does this mean that there is a problem with my baking setup? Currently, I have no reward for baking.

Can someone help check my address? https://tzscan.io/tz1e2meErj7eEfXwqr7bDK6N1YatmLaugfMp?default=baking

Answer (score 7):

```
Apr 15 05:23:46 - client.baking: No slot found at level 395863 (max_priority = 64)
```

This message is normal when you are not given any rights, so it's perfectly fine. There is no concern there.

Going into the details how you can check whether or not you are set up correctly on chain. The easiest way is to check on the "Delegate" status shown on [tzscan](https://tzscan.io/), specifically the "Active" status you already have there:

[image: Delegate Status]

Also, the fact that you had endorsement rights already is a hint that you are correctly set up. The more advanced way to check to see if you have registered correctly is to look for the "delegation" operation on chain. Tzscan does a great job showing this:

[image: Delegation tab]

The most bottom operation on the above screenshot is where you had the ["delegation" operation](https://tzscan.io/ooQALYf4m2pJqX4XLJ9KgbLtmRiv78HqBqDuifSpRLnuuVFGUNy) to register your baker address. This confirms that you are indeed registered on chain and the chain will assign you rights as long as you have roll(s) and you don't become [inactive](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alphanet/introduction/howtorun.html#inactive-delegates).

As far as your baking rights, under the "Bakings" tab, if you look at the below screenshot with the "#Blocks" column, you have baking rights coming up in the future cycles, namely cycle 97 (2) and 99 (1):

[image: Tzscan Bakings Tab]

So you are good to go, be prepared for your first block to bake in cycle 97! It may be helpful to look at your rights using [bakendorse](https://bakendorse.com) with [your address](https://bakendorse.com/#/bakers/tz1e2meErj7eEfXwqr7bDK6N1YatmLaugfMp/dashboard) instead as it gives you an estimation when your next bake/endorse right is.

Comment: do you know why my Baking Success is too low?

Comment: this isn't the right place to follow up with a different question. I would ask another question instead if you can't find another relevant answer here.